# ⚽️ World Cup Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

To complete my first half you need my final second half.

I might help you achieve your goal. Your chances are better if we’re well acquainted.

Hint:

> I rhyme with the product of shearing sheep in the rain.

Comment: Yay Croatia won! Going up against France! HRVATSKA!!!!

Comment: This riddle came to me while watching the Croatia-England game. At the time, England was winning.

Comment: This is soo hard...

Comment: Note the "wordplay" tag. What do I mean by "first half" and "second half"?

Comment: I'm hoping it will be solved by Sunday, so here's a hint: It's a two word phrase.

Comment: My first half can take a long time if you’re a South African tennis player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a free kick:

> SET PIECE

To complete my first half you need my final second half.

> If you have a missing piece, you wouldn't have the set.

I might help you achieve your goal. Your chances are better if we’re well acquainted.

> Better chance of scoring a goal if you're well practised with set pieces.

I rhyme with the product of shearing sheep in the rain.

> Set piece and wet fleece.

⚽️⚽️⚽️ ⚽️⚽️⚽️⚽️⚽️ + 'My first half can take a long time if you’re a South African tennis player'

> Enumeration (3,5) + Kevin Anderson won the 2018 Wimbledon Men's SF with a final set 26-24.

Well done France and Croatia.

Comment: Well done indeed!

Comment: I’m curious, do you think you could have solved it with only the first two clues? What subset of clues would you recommend to calibrate the difficulty for this community?

Comment: I only got it when looking at the end and saw the rhyme - was way off the mark with the first clues. Had an early thought it was 'game over' -  go|ld & sil|ver with a half-ti|me in the middle. Still it was within range. Now seeing the first clue as the final last one needed to complete the first one it was original and good! (I understand there was time pressure to complete this match.)

Comment: *"Taking a free kick"* hahah love it, $(+1)$

Answer (score 3):

It might be

> Finals

Because

> You need to finish both halves of the bracket (semifinals) to get to the finals.

And

> If you win the semis, you go to the finals, and when you win the finals, you achieve your goal (the trophy). The better prepared you are, the better you will be.

**EDIT**: changed answer

Comment: You’re thinking along the right lines with the last part.

Comment: Saw your edit. It’s not a synonym or any way related to your original idea. You have the right general idea in the third part of your answer, but you need to figure out the rest of the clue. I’ve updated the question. The way the clue was worded at first was awkward. Probably put the solution too far out of reach.